# How do I bind Polymer property in setTimeout?

Tags: polymer

I have a Polymer property defined as:

```
properties: {
  delay: {
   type: Timeranges,
   value: '5000'
  }
}
```

And I use this property as a timeout like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  request = ajax(request, custParams, inputValue.trim(), input, result, component.subType, component.queryParams);
}, "{{delay}}");
```

But this is not working. If I specify a literal number as a function argument instead of `"{{delay}}"`, it works fine. How do I bind `delay` here?

Answer (score 1):

The property type should be `Number` (not `Timeranges`).

Polymer's [data binding syntax](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding) can only be used in HTML (not JavaScript). Your current code passes a literal string to `setTimeout()` instead of the numeric value of `delay`.

Assuming `setTimeout()` is called from your Polymer object definition, you would use `this.delay` like this:

```
Polymer({
  properties: {
    delay: {
      type: Number,
      value: 5000
    }
  },
  foo: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {...}, this.delay);
  }
});
```

If you need `setTimeout()` to be called whenever `delay` changes, you would use an [observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#change-callbacks) like this:

```
Polymer({
  properties: {
    delay: {
      type: Number,
      value: 5000,
      observer: '_delayChanged'
    }
  },
  _delayChanged: function(newDelay) {
    setTimeout(function() {...}, newDelay);
  }
  // ...
});
```